# cpp fast access to binary data on disk

Tags: c++, database, binary, indexing

Currently, my program have a lot of sessions at memory. Session is the object with `unsigned int ID`, some variables + possible long size `std::map` (different size from session to session).

I want to unload some sessions to disk, but does not know how to organize structure on the disk to have opportunity for fast session finding on disk to load it when need. How to fast find session by ID on disk? Maybe some indexes, but does not know how to use them... or maybe some additional variable?

**SQL Database ** is not my variant, because stability, resource overuse, portability, compability etc. etc. etc. need to organize something like other databases do on disk.

*thanks, and sorry for my english. please, edit my text if it have mistakes*

Comment: All of the reasons you list for not using an SQL database are actually advantages of such databases. They are very, very stable. They're available on pretty much every platform. SQL is a portable standard. And so on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz its hard to explain `why` on not native language, but for my task, I can not use third-party database. already migrated from mysql to own binary files database. currently, its very simple save/load base on start and exit & buckup, but I want to realize some advanced features as described. Also, I need much more control, when data can be stored on the disk and when it can be unloaded from the memory (more advanced memory management and disk usage that sql can provide). 2) sql is not so fast 3) library/process requests additional memory - better to store sessions at this memory.

Comment: It's very, very unlikely that you'll be able to make your own solution that works better than the solutions everyone else uses and recommends. We use them and recommend them for a reason. If you have a long list of specific features you need, you'll have to code them all. We certainly can't point you to a solution that meets your specific requirements if you will not or cannot document them in detail. I strongly urge you to look at lightweight databases such as [Tokyo Cabinet](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/). Writing your own is a major undertaking and likely to suck.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The fact of the matter is that I working with objects most of the time and data on disk need only for buckup and store not used for a long time records. I do not need all SQL syntax and features. seems, only the way to `quick search at the binary file for position of my session`. thanks, for `Tokyo Cabinet`, interesting and useful, but not at the current project, but I found the idea at the documentation: `The size of the database is proportional to the range of keys and the limit size of each value.` so, if I will limit each session by size, I will be able to seek by index for

Comment: seems I need to search for information how to implement simple `Table database` on the disk. like described here http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html paragraph: Flexible Implementation of Table Database. `Tokyo Cabinet` also provide much more features that I need. (I need only the way to serizlize/unserialize objects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on so many sites such as this do so many answer a simple question with, "Why do you want to do that?" or offer alternatives that are not answering the person? (Read the "Your Answer" box at the bottom of this page) It may be that there are better ways, or the person is pretty much wasting their time. But, they may be trying just for the fun of trying and coming up with a solution no matter how well it functions. @abrahab obviously wants to have a go at doing this (and he's tried to make that very clear) so let him, just answer his question or if you don't know the answer keep quiet.

@abrahab, one way is to use a binary file format to store the session data. Use a btree index for the session ids (Google btree) saved in a separate file, the value stored in the btree under each session id is a file pointer to the position in the data file where the binary record starts. The first bytes (short int, int, long) read from the file tell you the length of the record in bytes, read in those bytes and process them. Up to you to define the format of the session record (struct, whatever). If you edit/delete/insert a record you must update the btree for that record and any record being re-positioned within the data file.

It's easier to use a DB but if this is what you want to do this will work and performance should be very good. If you want to search for specific values within the record you could build another btree with those values but that would be when to seriously consider going down the DB route.

Comment: thanks! its exactly what I am searching for! and its hard to describe for all on not a native language that I need `files` realization, not DB! I got the idea, will think about its how to code it. many thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck, this site has a Java animation of how a btree index works that should get you started: http://slady.net/java/bt/

Comment: thanks for the link, will start with this after solve other problem that block all threads of applications on `pipe` + `fgets`. If you do not mind I will accept you answer later. I think its good if others will read it and got that "simle use DB" is not an answer. Also you will get more votes. :)

Answer (score 6):

Use a database, this is exactly what they are good for.

Comment: no, database is not my variant for many reasons. I want to realize something like my own.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`SQLite`](http://www.sqlite.org/) library for that purpose. It has [C/C++ interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) as well.

Also, SQLite is a [cross-platform and portable](http://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) database. It is just a file (you can have a single-file), like any other files on your harddisk. You don't need to install any huge software for that. It is light and handy.